# update main activity ui from a callback in login activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a navigation drawer in main activity `A` and a login activity `B`. Activity `B` has a `OnLogin callback` in which i update a global userinfo from a singleton which main activity can access. Note that this `OnLogin callback` is invoked in a thread.

Now I want to update main activity navigation drawer header ui (e.g. user name and user icon). I'm using `startActivityForResult` in main activity `A` to get a flag from login activity `B` to indicate that something has changed and then update UI in `OnActivityResult`.

The problem I'm facing is that when activity `B` finishes (triggered by `OnBackPressed` in activity `B`), the `OnLogin` callback doesn't necessary get called. As a result, `onActivityResult` won't necessary pick up the change made in `UserInfo`. My question is, what is a proper way of updating UI in this case?

Comment: I think use observble may to what you are looking for .http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observable.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing

UserInfo.java

```
class UserInfo extends Observable {
  private String value_;
  public void setValue(String value)
  {
    value_ = value;
    setChanged();
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        // other onCreate stuff
        Singleton.getInstance().getUserInfo().addObserver(this);
        // UserInfo initialization
        ...
        // UI initialization
        Singleton.getInstance().getUserInfo().notifyObservers();
     }

     public void update(Observable observable, Object data)
     {
        if (observable instanceof UserInfo)
        {
           //update ui
        }
     }
 }
```

LoginActivity.java

```
     OnLogin(String value)
     {
       UserInfo userInfo = Singleton.getInstance().getUserInfo();
       userInfo.setValue(value);
       userInfo.notifyObserver();
     }
```